# Apply shape to a model but not to the armature

Tags: modeling, armature, bones

I posed a model using an armature and I now need to apply the shape to the model, so that it becomes it's default pose.

But I need the armature to not be affected by this new default pose. Think of it as a guy with his arm raised but the bones of the arm are still hanging down. Plus, I still need to be able to control the arm with them. (It would look horrible but it's just an example)

Is there a way to do this? I've been unable to find an answer.

Comment: Sounds like simple applying of armature modifier will do the trick. Just make a copy of this modifier.

Comment: Ha! I didn't know you could do that. It worked, thanks a lot!